# Solrcloud - facet.field error using alias

Tags: solr, alias, facet

I really need help in the scenario that I'll describe.
I am using alias for two different collections - users and machines.

command used to create the alias:

```
host:port/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATEALIAS&name=useragen&collections=users,machines
```

This query list all both users and machine:

```
host:port/solr/useragen/select?q=*:*
```

When I excute this query :

```
host:port/solr/myalias/select?q=*%3A*&wt=json&indent=true&facet=true&user_id=facet.field
```

So I get a error as result:

```
"msg": "undefined field: \" user_id \ ""
```

My question is:
It's possible set my `facet.field` to `myalias`?
I need to set it in a xml file?

The facet.field for both collections are correctly configurated in solrconfig.xml but, this does'nt work using alias (myalias)

Thanks!

Comment: Should the facet.query be against `host:port/solr/useragen/select` and not `myalias`? And `user_id=facet.field` should be `facet.field=user_id` ?

Comment: Thanks! You are right! Problem was ctrl+c and ctrl+v... The problem is when I use a alias for 2 collections. Useragen is a alias for coll1 and coll2. This query doesn't facting "host:port/solr/useragen/select?q=*%3A*&wt=json&indent=true&facet=true&facet.field=user_id" but this works: "host:port/solr/useragen/select?q=*%3A*&wt=json&indent=true&facet=true&facet.field=id" Why when I use id field It's works? The __user_id__ is configured in both __solrconfig.xlm__ and schema.xml.

Comment: Well, that should be `facet.field=user_id`, not `facet.field:user_id`. user_id should not be configured in solrconfig.xml, but the configuration in schema.xml is important. Add it to your question, and please, be exact about what you're trying and what requests you are making. In addition, the exact errors would be useful (from the log file, non-edited).